# Reduce html table height and overscroll - HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this table in a modal form. The table is being populated with lot of data but then i do not want to paginate. Rather, i want to reduce the height of the table in the modal form and add an overflow for the table. Below is my code but then it doesn't do the trick.

How do i achieve this please?

**CSS**

```
 #table{
     height:20px;
     overflow:scroll;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <form method="post" action="#" >
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Select Persons</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box-body">    
    <table  class="table" id="table"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
        </tr>

</thead>
<tbody >
 @foreach($people as $person)
<tr id="{{$person->id}}">
<td>{!! $person->name !!}</td>
</tr> 
@endforeach 
</tbody>
</table>
             </div>

        <div class="modal-footer" >
        <button type="submit"   class="btnsubmit">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</form> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: rather add the propertys to a table-wrapping element like '.box-body'

Comment: @johnSmith thanks that worked like magic but why isn't the table afftected when i use the .table property?

Comment: @LearnLaravel - Because according to [CSS - 17.5.3 Table height algorithms](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#height-layout) any non-auto value of "height" for a table is "treated as a minimum height". The table will always expand beyond that if necessary, so it never overflows.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your `table` inside a **container** with the same css properties.

```css
#container{
height:50px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}

table{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>col</td><td>col</td><td>col</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col</td><td>col</td><td>col</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col</td><td>col</td><td>col</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col</td><td>col</td><td>col</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col</td><td>col</td><td>col</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col</td><td>col</td><td>col</td></tr>
    <tr><td>col</td><td>col</td><td>col</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```